# 504- Gateway timeout only in django function

Tags: python, django

I have a very mind-boggling problem and my team has struggled to solve it. We do have it narrowed down but not 100%.

### Introduction

We are trying to implement LTI in a Django app with the Vue frontend. To fetch the token from the URL the backend makes a `POST` request to the URL with data and should receive a token or error if it's expired or invalid.

### Design

---

Browser ---- POST REQUEST --> view function on `Server (Django)` --- POST REQUEST --> `Auth URL`

### Problem

---

The post request that Django view makes times out with `504 Gateway Timeout`. This could be normal if the server takes a lot of time. However, increasing the time did not help and checked Auth URL with POSTMAN it worked fine and was not down.

**What I have tried**

---

We decided to debug or diagnose this issue that why a code block works in a function when it is called through a shell but not when it is called by a `POST` request does not.

1. Eliminated the front end and used `POSTMAN` to send a `POST` request to my Django server -- timeout on the Auth URL
2. Called the same function using `Django` `shell` -- worked
3. Copied the code into a separate python file outside Django -- worked
4. Used same virtual env for all above

**What it appears to be**

---

When a POST function is called and another post request is made inside it then it times out. Please note: If I make a `POST` request in the same situation with invalid data (say missing `grant_type`) then it does not time out.

---

Code Block

---

```
auth_request = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_assertion_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer",
    "client_assertion": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlJVbzNJWWlSR0ZDYUhNNEg0S2lid095enAtRU9KWlAweXkwd0g3bk5VOEEifQ.eyJpc3MiOiI2NjkxNmZmYy03YjE5LTQ0MWEtYjE5Zi0yOGQxMzVmYjZjOWYiLCJzdWIiOiI2NjkxNmZmYy03YjE5LTQ0MWEtYjE5Zi0yOGQxMzVmYjZjOWYiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2RldmVsb3Blci5ibGFja2JvYXJkLmNvbS9hcGkvdjEvZ2F0ZXdheS9vYXV0aDIvand0dG9rZW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NTMyODcyNzMsImV4cCI6MTY1MzI4NzMzOCwianRpIjoibHRpLXNlcnZpY2UtdG9rZW4tMDQyZTZhNjctNDA2My00YmQ1LWI2NmQtNTM4YjU2ZTllM2Q1In0.8Jaou965cPTCFv-7yP9iIlH8mMgQjAi0AR2li0KwCcRuHsRZ_1OpbE83bZ06RMXhbjA4crRqTI4zMi8aNfq16Mkg4lXoPj8JiJW7q8b_ZQ1rLZvIojmabehYjpyscHRitFPLibfTYF2mCjUyHqwPgnFRLNrHIVuSvM0BiK56PuYK6SiiSjxu2U3bmJqOHNW2mqx2YYfkaXx2u7ru6CKTiL3KBGzFPYjCUwwWNBdbz4R0g0aHK_l-hhA3oi_pCDZOyqdnyCmGAj5SpZbuZOqrZbQBrqPoEFtXdNDPpHGGwW7IUbbmCtsmE2NqQiYt6snmK-1pbxsLxE0mXrpDqASh4A",
    "scope": "https://purl.imsglobal.org/spec/lti-nrps/scope/contextmembership.readonly",
}
response = requests.post(
    "https://developer.blackboard.com/api/v1/gateway/oauth2/jwttoken",
    data=auth_request,
)
response = response.json()
print(response)
```

Comment: Just a guess here: how about CSRF settings? Did you try to appy https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt decorator on the view?

Comment: @DušanMaďar ill try that tomorrow. Thing is the view itself is called file. Its when view makes a `POST` request that is what fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days of trying to figure it out, we deployed the project with `Production` settings and it worked. Upon investigation on why it was not working on staging we found the following:

1. Front end sends a POST request to the back end
2. Backend then encoded the data using the private key and sent it to a 3rd party server
3. Because 3rd party server needed to validate our `jwks` message it sent another request to a URL on our staging server.
4. This 3rd request was not addressed as the server only had one thread. Adding a threads parameter to `gunicorn` did the trick

`gunicorn ripple.wsgi --reload --log-level debug --threads 4`